# Mandar executar um loop novamente

Tags: java, lógica

Código:

```
while (digita != 4){
    System.out.println("Digite o o número referente ao tamanho da(s) pulseira(s)\n1.Pequena (17cm) - R$180,00\n2.Média (18cm) - R$200,00\n3.Grande (20cm) - R$240,00\n4.Prosseguir para escolha de pingentes.");
    digita = in.nextInt();
    switch(digita){
        case 1:
        valor += 180;
        tamanhopulseira = 17;
        quantidadepequena += 1;
        break;
        case 2:
        valor += 200;
        tamanhopulseira = 18;
        quantidademedia += 1;
        break;
        case 3:
        valor += 240;
        tamanhopulseira = 20;
        quantidadegrande += 1;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Total: " +valor);
}
if(digita==4 && tamanhopulseira == 0){
    System.out.println("Você deve escolher pelo menos uma pulseira de qualquer tamanho!");
}
```

Bom, neste código quando o usuário escolhe a opção 4 sem ter escolhido nenhuma das outras opções, o programa manda uma mensagem de erro, mas como eu faço para junto dessa opção de erro ele mandar o usuário de volta para o `while`?

Comment: Tem alguma resposta que resolveu? Pode aceitar alguma delas?

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim:

```
while (digita != 4) {
    System.out.println("Digite o o número referente ao tamanho da(s) pulseira(s)\n1.Pequena (17cm) - R$180,00\n2.Média (18cm) - R$200,00\n3.Grande (20cm) - R$240,00\n4.Prosseguir para escolha de pingentes.");
    digita = in.nextInt();
    switch(digita) {
        case 1:
            valor += 180;
            tamanhopulseira = 17;
            quantidadepequena += 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            valor += 200;
            tamanhopulseira = 18;
            quantidademedia += 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            valor += 240;
            tamanhopulseira = 20;
            quantidadegrande += 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (tamanhopulseira == 0) {
                System.out.println("Você deve escolher pelo menos uma pulseira de qualquer tamanho!");
                digita = 0;
            }
        default:
            System.out.println("Você deve escolher de 1 à 4");
    }
    System.out.println("Total: " +valor);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/RepeatLoop.java).

Está verificando se se alguma pulseira foi selecionada se digitar o 4 e não deixa sair do laço até que uma pelo menos uma delas tenha sido escolhida. E também mantém no laço se algo inválido for digitado.

Comment: Na verdade esse seu código exibe essa mensagem para qualquer valor diferente de 1,2,3 ou 4. No meu caso eu queria que essa mensagem aparecesse quando o usuário tentasse prosseguir para o pagamento direto, sem escolher nenhuma pulseira entende?

Comment: Entendo. O que acontece se a pessoa digitar 5? ou 40? Ou "quatro"? Provavelmente estamos errando no que você quer porque você está fazendo algo errado no resto do código. Provavelmente todo o código esteja errado e não só esta parte. Seria mais fácil você definir o problema com exatidão.

Comment: Para este problema de outro valor ser digitado você está correto podemos usar o default. Mas e caso a pessoa tente ir direto para o pagamento? como eu faço para exibir esta mesma mensagem e mostrar novamente as opções?

Comment: O que determina que ela quer ir direto para o pagamento e que ela não pode ir? E quando ela pode ir direto para o pagamento?

Comment: nesse loop a pessoa vai escolher quantas pulseiras ela vai querer, pode ser 1 pequena, 1 pequena e 1 grande, 2 de cada e assim que ela acaba de escolher a opção 4 manda ela para escolha de pingentes. Desculpe eu escrevi errado no comentario anterior.

Comment: Não sei se esta á melhor forma de fazer isto mas também não sei se entendi o que você quer fazer. Vou considerar que `tamanhopulseira` começa com zero. Não sei se isto resolve tudo o que você quer e precisa mas com a alteração, acho que resolve o principal. Alguma coisa me diz que esse controle de tamanho da pulseira não está correto mas pode ser que eu não esteja entendendo para que isto serve. Como imagino que isto seja um exercício não vai causar muitos problemas, mas em código real isto seria uma pesadelo de manutenção.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque um `while` em volta de tudo, que só sai quando uma variável booleana estiver setada, e só coloque `true` nessa variável quando tudo estiver preenchido de forma correta:

```
boolean opcaoEscolhida = false;
while (!opcaoEscolhida){
    while (digita != 4){
        System.out.println("Digite o o número referente ao tamanho da(s) pulseira(s)\n1.Pequena (17cm) - R$180,00\n2.Média (18cm) - R$200,00\n3.Grande (20cm) - R$240,00\n4.Prosseguir para escolha de pingentes.");
        digita = in.nextInt();
        switch(digita){
            case 1:
              valor += 180;
              tamanhopulseira = 17;
              quantidadepequena += 1;
              opcaoEscolhida = true;
              break;
            case 2:
              valor += 200;
              tamanhopulseira = 18;
              quantidademedia += 1;
              opcaoEscolhida = true;
              break;
            case 3:
              valor += 240;
              tamanhopulseira = 20;
              quantidadegrande += 1;
              opcaoEscolhida = true;
              break;
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " +valor);
    }
    if(!opcaoEscolhida){
        System.out.println("Você deve escolher pelo menos uma pulseira de qualquer tamanho!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Testei e a mensagem caiu num loop infinito, ela não para de ser mostrada :/

Comment: Realmente... tem que resetar o valor da variável `digita` para que o `while` que interage com o usuário entre novamente.

Comment: Agora que entendi melhor o código, a opção 4 seria para sair sem escolher nenhuma das opções... mas antes o usuário já teria de ter escolhido alguma, sendo possível escolher várias se assim desejar.

Comment: Editei pra refletir este cenário.